# How to use Induction with Sequences?

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-writing, induction, contest-math

I have posted this similar question here, but with no hopes. I would just like to know:

[image]

[image]

Most of the solution I have no issue with. Look at where they say:

"Choose a representation $(n - 3^m)/2 = s_1 + ... + s_k$ in the desired form.

But to do that first, they applied induction to the set:

$$A = \{1, 2, 3, ..., n-1\}$$

You have to ensure,

$$\frac{n - 3^m}{2} \le n-1$$

How do you show that?

Lets, consider the case, $n=5$. It follows,

$$3^1 < 5 < 3^2$$, Hence, $m = 1$ which gives:

$$\frac{5 - 3}{2} \le 4 \implies 1 < 4 \checkmark$$

But the question is how to prove it?

Suppose:

$$\frac{n - 3^m}{2} \le n-1$$

I am to prove:

$$\frac{n + 1 - 3^m}{2} \le n$$

Begin with the hypothesis,

$$\frac{n - 3^m}{2} \le n-1$$

$$\frac{n - 3^m}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \le n- \frac{1}{2} < n$$

Since $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I suppose the statement is proved. Can you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{n-3^m}{2}\leq n-1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $n-3^m \leq 2n-2$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2-3^m\leq n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $2-n\leq 3^m$, which is clearly true for any $n,m\in\mathbb N$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $m=\lfloor\log_3n\rfloor$. This means that $m\le\log_3n<m+1$ and hence that $3^m\le n<3^{m+1}$. It follows that $n-3^m<3^{m+1}-3^m$ and hence that

$$\frac{n-3^m}2<\frac{3^{m+1}-3^m}2=\frac{3^m(3-1)}2=3^m\le n\;.$$

That is,

$$\frac{n-3^m}2<n\;.\tag{1}$$

Since we’re assuming in this case that $n$ is odd, we know that $\frac{n-3^m}2$ is an integer, $(1)$ implies that

$$\frac{n-3^m}2\le n-1\;.$$

Comment: @BrianScott, good answer as always. I believe then my proof is incorrect?

Comment: @Amad27: I'm afraid so. It has a serious problem right at the beginning: you haven't taken into account the fact that $m$ depends on $n$. When you replace $n$ by $n+1$, $m$ may change.

Comment: @BrianScott, Why cant I ever get these.....? Also, how is: $m = \floor \log_3(n) \floor$? Can you give me a definition in the inequality for the floor function? I dont see how:

$$m = \floor \log_3(n) \floor \implies m \le \log_{3}(n) < n+1$$ ?? Thanks!

Comment: @BrianScott Please will you guide me?

Comment: @Amad27: I do apologize: I had a bunch of typos in the first two lines where my fingers wrote $n$ instead of $m$. See if it makes more sense now; if not, let me know exactly what isn’t clear.